# Should I store emails in my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imap

In theory, I'm looking to integrate email into a CRM I'm building.  I'd like for each contact with an email address to have those sent and received emails fetched when viewing that contact with a connected IMAP account.

Would one store these emails in the database or would it be faster/more efficient to fetch these emails on the fly? (when the contact page is accessed via a GET request).

Comment: no way to answer: how fast is your imap server? how fast is the link to the imap server? How many emails will be stored on this imap server? If you have to download/parse 50 kajillion emails to parse out the addresses, you just MIGHT be better off doing that ONCE and caching the results in your db.

Comment: I don't know how fast the server or the link is, unfortunately.  We're talking a few thousand emails for now, but always growing of course.  It sounds like the easier solution would be to store those emails in the database.  Thanks for the comment, Marc.

Comment: It may make a lot more sense to integrate into your smtp server and deliver directly into your service, rather than trying to use IMAP to fetch it after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

> Would one store these emails in the database or would it be faster/more efficient to fetch these emails on the fly?

Have you measured the performance to find out?  Don't prematurely optimize, actually identify bottlenecks.  Set up some tests (large-scale, repeatable... don't just test one email one time) to retrieve emails from the CRM system vs. retrieving them from the database.  See if there's a significant difference.  Include that information in your decision-making process.

Additionally, there are other things to consider when making this decision.  Namely:

1. Will these emails be modified in the scope of a transaction?  Databases are good at participating in a transaction scope for a unit of work in your code, third-party services and APIs not so much.  You might want to put them in the database if they're needed as part of such a scope.  (Though given the description, that's unlikely.)
2. Duplicating data between multiple systems (multiple "sources of truth") and keeping it synchronized is *hard*.  It introduces a lot of unexpected complexity into a system.  You may see a performance gain, but is it worth it?  Maybe some application-level caching will yield just as much of a gain without duplicating the data and introducing another dependency into the mix?

Comment: Thank you!  I'll definitely look into testing performance and factor that into my decision. 1. Emails will NOT be modified. 2. Not sure just yet if I need anything to be synchronized beyond the initial pull of information, but if I could keep the emails out of my database, I'd imagine that would be ideal.

Comment: I could use this method to only pull the pertinent emails, right?  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-search